How to use a mocked object in a Moq callback (or other method)?
I'm mocking the following interface:
public interface IVirtualFile
{
    string Contents { get; set; }
    // ...
    void SaveToDisk();
    // ...
}

To test this class:
public class InformationHandler
{
    // ...
    public void PrepareAndSaveSpecificInfo(IVirtualFile p_objSaveFile)
    {
        // ...
        p_objSaveFile.Contents = z_strBeginning;
        // ...
        p_objSaveFile.Contents = String.Concat(p_objSaveFile.Contents, z_strOtherInformation);
        // ...
        p_objSaveFile.Contents = String.Concat(p_objSaveFile.Contents, z_strEnd);
        p_objSaveFile.SaveToDisk();
    }
    // ...
}

With this:
[TestFixture]
public TestInformationHandler
{
    private Mock<IVirtualFile> _mockVirtualFile { get; set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void CreateMocks()
    {
        // ...
        _mockVirtualFile = new Mock<IVirtualFile>();

        _mockVirtualFile.Setup(vf => vf.SaveToDisk()).Callback(() => CheckSavedData());
        // ...
    }

    private void CheckSavedData()
    {
        // ...
    }    

    [Test]
    public void Test_PrepareAndSaveSpecificInfo()
    {
        // ...
        PrepareAndSaveSpecificInfo(_mockVirtualFile);
        // ...
    }    
}

The thing is, I want CheckSavedData() to use Assert to test the Contents property of my mock object.
So how can I pass said mock object to the method? Or should I make mockVirtualFile a property of TestVirtualFile and use it in CheckSavedData()?
EDIT: as mentioned in the comments to vhr's answer, what I was thinking of isn't feasible, simply because a mock object's Object property's properties don't keep the values set.
To make it even clearer, step-by-step debugging indicates that right after
_mockVirtualFile.Contents = "abcdef";

the property _mockVirtualFile.Contents still returns null.

What are you testing? Since it's not the real SafeToDisk being called you can probably disregard anything it does. You should assert what your actual code does, not the mock.

I'm testing a method that sets Contents. Since SaveToDisk() saves Contents to a file it makes sense to check the value of the latter in the method's mock.

It's not clear why what has been sketched here doesn't work. Please edit the question so that it contains a minimal, reproducible example.

@MarkSeemann: Indeed, I hadn't noticed that it wasn't that clear. I've included the class that uses IVirtualFile and is the one actually tested. Is that clearer now? Apologies for taking so much time, another task had taken priority.

By using 'Setup', you are mocking the 'SaveToDisk' method behavior which means that you are telling Moq to execute the callback each time you call your object's method from test:
private Mock<IVirtualFile> mockVirtualFile;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void CreateMocks()
{
    // ...
    mockVirtualFile = new Mock<IVirtualFile>();

    mockVirtualFile.Setup(vf => vf.SaveToDisk()).Callback(() => CheckSavedData());
    // ...
}
 
 [Test]
 public void TestMethod()
 {
      var mockedFile = mockVirtualFile.Object;
      mockedFile.SaveToDisk(); //this will call CheckSavedData() method
      ...
 }

so if you want to do any assertion you can just do e.g:
mockedFile.SaveToDisk();
Assert.True(mockedFile.Contents == null)

As the Moq framework is used to 'mock' some behavior you should actually modify your 'Contents' property inside your mocked method otherwise there is no point in asserting the 'Contents' as it will be always null...

So you are saying that what I want to do (using Assert within CheckSavedData() to tests Contents) can't be done? I left that out to save space, but SaveToDisk() is actually called within another method (that takes an IVirtualFile parameter) and it's that method I want to test.  Should I then test Contents after calling that method?

By the way, I hope that the previous comment doesn't come across as too confrontational. Apologies if it does; I just meant to make sure I had fully understood what you meant.

@Jean-DavidLanz no problem :) I'm saying that if you set up your object method using Moq then the code from your 'Callback' will be called (when using mockVirtualFile.Object.SaveToFile()).

@Jean-DavidLanz Is your idea to create a concrete instance (of IVirtualFile) and then pass it to Moq to run the assert? If so, then it is not what Moq is used for. Moq is used to create a "substitute" for the real thing so that you can test something without creating a it (and possibly set up the whole PROD environment)...

The purpose of mocking is to isolate and focus on the code being tested and not on the behavior or state of external dependencies. In mocking, the dependencies are replaced by closely controlled replacements objects that simulate the behavior of the real ones.

All right, I understand (after checking with my own code). You can set a property of a mock object's Object property, but it won't keep the value. I'm editing (again) my question to reflect that and gratefully accepting your answer. Thanks!

@Jean-DavidLanz you are welcome ;)
